When running "docker-compose up" I get the following message "services.links must be a mapping"
In my docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3.7'
services:
# REST API running on Node JS container
 app:
  container_name: lafs-api
  restart: always
  build: .
  ports:
    - '3000:3000'
# link this container to the Mongo DB container
 links:
  - mongo
# pass in environment variables for database host and name
 environment:
   - DB_HOST=mongo
   - DB_NAME=lafs-db
# Mongo DB storage container
 mongo:
  container_name: lafs-db
  image: 'mongo:4'
  ports:
  - '27017:27017'
# Attach the external network to these containers
networks:
 default:
  external:
   name: lafs-net

I have been checking the indentation but now I am stumped. Any ideas what I can fix?
I tried running the error code in google to see if there was a solution out there but all the ones I saw are different than mine. This is the error message "services.links must be a mapping".

links: (and also environment:) are indented one step less than they need to be, so they look like they're top-level services and not properties of the app service.  That having been said, links: is an obsolete artifact of first-generation Docker networking, and you should be able to just delete that block entirely.
